# PHP - Тестирование Процедурного Кода

Tags: php, phpunit

Интересует вопрос, читаю сейчас про unit тестирование , в том числе про 
`PHPUNIT Framework`

В примерах и на хабре показывают только тестирование `ООП` Кода 
Интересует, можно ли через `PHPUNIT` тестировать `процедурный код` 
Либо есть ли аналогичные `Frameworks` для `процедурного` подхода? 
Былбы благодарен за линк на статью

Comment: А что именно вам мешает тестировать процедурный код через PHPUnit?

Answer (score 4):

**some.php**

```
<?php

function add($a, $b) {
    // Validation here.
    return $a + b;
}
```

**test/some.php**

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require('some.php');
// or use autoload.

class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testAdd()
    {
        // Assert
        $this->assertEquals(3, add(1, 2));
        //...
    }
}
```

http://respect.github.io/Validation/

**Respect\Validation**

```
<?php
    use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
    require('some.php');

    if (!v::equals(3)->validate(add(1, 2))) {
        "Error";
    }
```

Или еще лучше ни каких библиотек:

```
<?php
    require('some.php');

    if (3 !== add(1, 2)) {
        "Error";
    }
```

Comment: было бы клево дополнить минимальными комментариями

Comment: @Etki Не совсем уверен. Коментарии к коду или просто описание?

Comment: да, я видел этот код, из статьи habrahabr, но он в ООП стиле, а мне нужен пример на процедурном)
Хотя уже нашел codeception, он более понятный, хотя уже phpunit доходит потихоньку к голове

Comment: @S1lllver Тогда у вас вопрос задан не правильно. ;)

Comment: @S1lllver Вам на самом деле подайдет любоя библиотека валидатор например http://respect.github.io/Validation/. Пишите как хотите а потом запускайте тест через `php test.php`

Comment: @S1lllver Обновил ответ.